# 16.04 intel HD 520 thinkpad problem

Tags: 16.04, intel, thinkpad

I just bought a thinkpad t460s and installed a fresh version of ubuntu 16.04. I'm using chrome and i get a very annoying flicker at some pages and youtube, and I also tryed to play a game and the frame rate was poor and there were some obvious graphical issues. Do you know what  would be the best way to have optimal drivers for this setup? I could even downgrade to a previous version. Also, I'm very new to linux, so if you can help me and tell me what commands to put in the terminal according to the solution I would be very grateful. Thank you a lot!

`antonio@sampi:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 `antonio@sampi:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07) Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Integrated Graphics Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo`

Answer (score -1):

If you have an AMD GPU in your laptop then this problem can't be solved until the release of Ubuntu 16.04.1 on July 21st. Since Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support the propriety AMD driver "fglrx". And this is a GPU driver problem.

On the other hand, if you have an nVidia GPU inside. Just go to `System Settings -> Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers`. Then check the driver of your GPU and install it.